# Select row in data after search using selectizeinput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I want to select data after putting in some keywords. I want to keep repeating that process of select data after putting in some keywords.
For example, I want to select Mazda cars and Maserati cars. I don't want to put in Mazda keywords and Maserati keywords together to get the data. I want to key in the Mazda keyword and select data and then delete Mazda and key in the Maserati keyword in the search box above the data.
The problem with my code is if I delete Mazda and key in Maserati, the selected row before this is deleted.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
mtcars_df <- rownames_to_column(mtcars)
names(mtcars_df)[1] <- "Name"
mtcars_df$Keywords <- ""
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars_df)){
  temp1 <- strsplit(as.character(tolower(str_squish(mtcars_df$Name[i])))," ")[[1]]
  for (j in 1:length(temp1)){
    mtcars_df$Keywords[i] <- paste0(mtcars_df[i, "Keywords"], trimws(gsub(",$","",temp1[j])), ", ")
  }
}

keywordschoice <- sort(trimws(unique(tolower(gsub(",$","",unlist(strsplit(mtcars_df$Keywords, ",")))))))
## create the interactive 
ui <- fluidRow(column(9, offset = 1,
                    selectizeInput(inputId = "keywords", label = "Select keyword(s)", choices = keywordschoice, selected = "Mazda", multiple = T),
                    br(),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("table2"),
                    br(),
                    actionButton("gobutton","Configure"),
                    br(),
                    br(),
                    htmlOutput("updated.df"),
                    br()
    ))

server <- shinyServer (
  function (input, output, session) {
    
    dataoftable <- reactive({
      database <- mtcars_df
      keywords <- c(input$keywords)
      if (is.null(keywords)){
        all_df_display <- mtcars_df 
      } else {
        all_df <- data.frame()
        for (i in 1:length(keywords)){
          df <- mtcars_df[grepl(keywords[i], mtcars_df$Keywords, perl = TRUE), ]
          all_df <- rbind(all_df, df)
        }
        all_df <- distinct(all_df)
        all_df$num <- str_count(all_df$Keywords, paste(keywords, collapse = "|"))
        all_df_display <- all_df %>% arrange(desc(num))
      }
      all_df_display        
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(dataoftable()   , server = TRUE, options = list(searching = FALSE))
    
    dataoftable2 <- reactive({
      s <- input$table_rows_selected
      df_input <- dataoftable()
      if(length(dataoftable())){
        df_input <- df_input[s, ]
      }
      df_input
    })
    
    output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(dataoftable2(), server = FALSE, options = list(searching = FALSE), editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1,2))))  ###
    
  }
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Is there any other way that I can do it?
Please let me know if anything not clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes to the dataframe you are using in outputs as

```
output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(mtcars_df   , server = TRUE, options = list(searching = FALSE))
output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(dataoftable(), server = FALSE, options = list(searching = FALSE), editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1,2))))
```

Then it works fine.  Also, I do not see `table_rows_selected` being defined anywhere in the `ui`. So, I am not sure how `dataoftable2` could have been defined. Hence, it was empty.